# How to make 5 minute countdown timer with RxJS and angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

The countdown should go from 4:59,4:58,....0:00.I tried this:

```
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input() since!: number
  readonly timeToShow$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(() => Math.floor((Date.now() / 1000 - this.since) / 60)),
  )
}
```

```
<span *ngIf="((timeToShow$ | async) || 0) > 0; else recentlyAdded">
    {{ timeToShow$ | async }} Minute{{ (timeToShow$ | async) === 1 ? '' : 's' }}
  </span>
```

But this gives me elapsed time from today's date. I just need a 5 minute countdown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a stopwatch to a count down timer in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273788/how-to-convert-a-stopwatch-to-a-count-down-timer-in-js)

Comment: Add 5 minutes to `since` and subtract the current time? Then you just need to properly format the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create an observable that emits decreasing integers every second for 300 seconds, you can do something like this:

```js
  secondsRemaining$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(n => 300 - n),
    takeWhile(n => n >= 0),
  );

  // emits: 300, 299, 298 ... 0
```

[`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timer) - emits increasing integers at the specified interval

[`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) - is used to reverse the increasing number into the time remaining

[`takeWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile) - completes the observable when the condition is met

---

If we use milliseconds, instead of seconds, we can use Angular's [`date`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) pipe to nicely format the time:

```html
<p> 
  {{ timeRemaining$ | async | date:'mm:ss' }}      <!-- ex: 03:47 -->
</p>
```

To put it into a component that takes the duration as an `@Input()`, it could look something like this:

```js
export class CountDownComponent {

  @Input() seconds = 300;

  timeRemaining$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(n => (this.seconds - n) * 1000),
    takeWhile(n => n >= 0),
  );

}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-angular-countdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcount-down%2Fcount-down.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcount-down%2Fcount-down.component.ts) demo.