# Countdown timer in Angular17

Tags: angular, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer in my home component. It kind of looks like this.

[image: The countdown]

Here is the place I put countdown in html file:

```
<div>
  {{displayTime}}
</div>
```

My Home.ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.countdownSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(val => this.displayTime = this.countdownTimer(val))
}

countdownTimer(seconds: number) {
   const totalSeconds = Math.floor((this.targetDay - Date.now()) / 1000);
   const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
   const hours = Math.floor((totalSeconds % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
   const minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % (60 * 60)) / 60);
   const remainingSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
   const formattedDays = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
   const formattedHours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
   const formattedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
   const formattedSeconds = remainingSeconds < 10 ? '0' + remainingSeconds : remainingSeconds;
   return formattedDays+":"+formattedHours+":"+formattedMinutes+":"+formattedSeconds
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.countdownSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

When I log it on console, it works fine:

[image]

But on my localhost:4200, it not loading and always spin around:

[image]

Even in the console or terminal, nothing like errors show up:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem, thank you a lot!!!

Comment: please check your terminal for any compilation issues, the code seems fine!

Comment: @NarenMurali nothing like error in the terminal or console, it just spins loading like that.

Comment: try incognito, different browser, restart server, or change the port `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000` might be also due to proxy/corporate proxy

Comment: You may find [this answer and demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74751002/1858357) helpful.

Comment: you are not settings displayTime anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget severals things:

```
 this.countdownSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(val =>
         //here you give value to the variable "displayTime"
         this.displayTime=this.countdownTimer(val)
 );

countdownTimer(seconds: number) {
   ...
   //you need return something
   return formattedDays+":"+formattedHours+":"+formattedMinutes+":"+formattedSeconds
}
```

BTW, you can use pipe async to makes Angular unsubscribe automatically

```
  countdownObs$!:Observable<string> //declare an observable

ngOnInit()
{
   //see that you **not** subscribe, simply transform the observable
   //using map
   this.countdownObs$= interval(1000).pipe(
       map(val =>this.countdownTimer(val))
    )
}
```

And you use

```
{{countdownObs$|async}}
```

pipe async mannage the unsubscription (don't forget import AsyncPipe or CommonModule in your component/Module)

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-w6h9ed?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with both approach

Comment: I've tried both ways, but none work. The browser is still loading.

Comment: I imagine the problem is that you're enter in loop when load (you have a . use F12 -in Web- to check what the navigator is loading) or your app is running in another port (not in 4200). The problem is not in the code.

Comment: I have routing in my angular project. the countdown timer will show up in the default open component when run ng serve. It always loading and show nothing. But when I change the link localhost to another route (Ex: localhost:4200/home -> localhost:4200/blog), it runs normal, and nothing wrong with the countdown timer.

Comment: Then check your routes, use [redirectTo](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects) or define a component for the path `''`

Comment: I use redirectTo for path' ' to go back to the component which contain the countdown timer
`{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},`